# Dynamically create widgets in sitefinity

Tags: asp.net, sitefinity

Is there some way in creating widgets dynamically (sitefinity)?

For example:
I have some html data in DB, so i want to get that data, create a widget and place the data in widget as html content.

Any idee or info will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built-in Content Block widget for this. See how to add it programmatically to a page [here](http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/developing-with-sitefinity-/adding-contentblock-to-a-page-via-fluent-api#RU_oK2LQ1UKyFqerJFV8bQ).